# Azure SDK 2.7.1 - WADLogTables : Improper Wad Log entries FormatedMessageEvent

Tags: azure

After we recently upgraded from 2.4 to 2.7.1 , all the log entries in the WADLogTables started looking like following

EventName="FormattedMessageEvent" FormattedMessage="Created {0} counters" Argument0="184" TraceSource="WaIISHost.exe"

Any idea ?